# PiCamera stream differences

Tags: python, streaming-video, picamera, h264

I'm trying to create a h264 stream from my Pi 3 and display it on an Android application.

After several attempts I found quite a simple solution:

```
raspivid -n -ih -t 0 -w 640 -h 480 -fps 25 -b 2000000 -l -o - | nc -l -p 5000
```

It works fine and I can play it through a common app like `VLC` on Windows:

```
vlc tcp/h264://my_pi_address:5000/
```

This stream can also be viewed on Android using a custom application (`RPi Camera Viewer`).

Reading **PiCamera** docs I found another solution using Python that should act the same way:

```
import socket
import time
import picamera

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 24

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
server_socket.listen(0)

# Accept a single connection and make a file-like object out of it
connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('wb')
try:
    camera.start_recording(connection, format='h264')
    camera.wait_recording(60)
    camera.stop_recording()
finally:
    connection.close()
    server_socket.close()
```

Tested through `VLC` it works fine but I'm unable to view this stream in Android. (At least not with `RPi Camera Viewer`).

I think one problem may come from minor differences between the stream's *structures* so how can I compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues in Android app visualization were given by a faulty network connection.

It is pretty difficult to say what happens in detail because I cannot investigate further on access point configuration and other network settings (including firewalls) active on company network since I've not network admin privileges, This's pretty frustrating. As a matter of fact using a different access point everything works as expected.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "faulty network connection"?

Comment: this's pretty difficult to say because I cannot investigate further on access point configuration or other network settings (including firewalls) active on company network since I've not network admin privileges.. this's pretty frustrating. As a matter of fact using a different access point everything works as expected.